# Given two css styles with equal points, who wins? Is this standard?

Tags: css

[I ran this test](http://jsbin.com/iloyoz), but I'd like to know what the standard says:

Given two css styles with equal points, who wins? My test seems to indicate the latter one does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS 2.1 section 6.4.1: [Cascading order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order):

> Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins.

Or, from the more recent, but still in working draft form, CSS 3 Cascading and inheritance: 6. [Cascading](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#cascading): Item 3:

> Order of appearance. The last declaration wins.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're right the last style is used (or the one with !important declaration, but that's different points)

Answer (score 1):

The selector which is defined later gets a higher precedence, in this case.

1. The importance of the selectors are determined
2. If they have the equal weight, the order of appearance are checked

   - Inline styles (`style=...`) have a higher importance than embedded stylesheets
   - Adding `!important` causes the property to take a higher precedence.

Comment: What do you mean by 'height' ?

Comment: Embedded stylesheets do **not** have higher importance then external stylesheets.

Comment: Style attributes do not have a higher importance then embedded stylesheets (they have a higher *specificity*)

Comment: Adding `!important` increases the importance for *any* declaration, not just non-inline ones.

Comment: Selectors don't have importance, they have specificity. Only declarations have importance.

Comment: Embedded stylesheets don't have a lower importance then external stylesheets either.