# React css modules override child styles

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules

I have a card component that accepts external class and its styles come from card.module.scss

```
export const Card = ({children, className}: any) => {
    return (
        <div className={classNames(styles.container, className)}>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}
 //card.module.scss
.container {
    padding: var(--spacer-s);
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    border-radius: var(--radi-m);
    display: flex;
    height: 150px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

I want to override height property in another component like this.

```
//home.tsx
<Card className={styles.card}>
  <CardSecondaryText>example</CardSecondaryText>
</Card>

//home.module.scss
.card {
    height: 214px;
}
```

But it didn't work. I don't want to use !important word. Any solution for this example will be great. Thanks.

Comment: I stumbled across the same issue. The problem is that your Card `<div>` will have both `.Card-module__container` and `.Home-module__card classes`, and since the specificity is the same, [the last css declaration wins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7702328/7424948). I wouldn't suggest this as a good solution, but what is likely is that `card.module.scss` appears after `home.module.scss` in the stylesheet, so you can maybe change that order by modifying the imports order (`import Card from 'Card.js';` before  `import styles from 'home.module.scss';` )